# Scrapy Error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny'

Tags: python, scrapy

I've put together a spider and it was running as intended until I've added the keyword `deny` into the rules.

This is my spider :

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from bhg.items import BhgItem

class BhgSpider (CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bhg'
    start_urls = ['http://www.bhg.com/holidays/st-patricks-day/']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'/*'], ),
                  deny=('blogs/*', 'videos/*', ),
                  callback='parse_html'), )

def parse_html(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    item = BhgItem()

    item['title'] = hxs.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
    item['h1'] = hxs.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
    item['canonical'] = hxs.xpath('//link[@rel = \"canonical\"]/@href').extract()
    item['meta_desc'] = hxs.xpath('//meta[@name=\"description"]/@content').extract()
    item['url'] = response.request.url
    item['status_code'] = response.status
    return item
```

When I run this code I get:

```
deny=('blogs/', 'videos/', ),), )
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny'
```

What am i doing wrong? Well, I guess a function or something was not expecting the extra argument (`deny`) but which function? `parse_html()`?

I did not define any other spiders and there is no `__init__()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deny` is supposed to be passed as an argument to `LinkExtractor`, but you put it outside those parentheses and passed it to `Rule`.  Move it inside, so you have:

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'/*'], deny=('blogs/*', 'videos/*', )),
                  callback='parse_html'), )
```

`__init__` is the method that is called when you pass arguments when instantiating a class, as you did here with the `Rule` and `LinkExtractor` classes.

Comment: Like I said above, I guess I've never checked where i've put `deny`. Thank you much

Answer (score 1):

Er, wouldn't it be the function you actually passed deny to? That would be Rule. The `__init__` is the internal method of the Rule class that is called when you construct the object.

The examples I found online with this pass `deny=` to the LinkExtractor, not the Rule. So you want:

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/*',),
                            deny=('blogs/*', 'videos/*', )),
              callback='parse_html'), )
```

Comment: Woow, I'm just blind. I guess I've never checked when I've put the `deny` Thank you much