# Scrapy error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website by extracting all links with "huis" (="house" in Dutch) in them. Following http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html, I'm trying

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from Funda.items import FundaItem

class FundaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Funda"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"
    ]

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*huis.*', callback='parse_item'))
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = FundaItem()
        item['title'] = response.extract()
        return item
```

However, I'm getting the error message

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*huis.*', callback='parse_item'))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
```

From a previous post ([Scrapy Error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730209/scrapy-error-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-deny)) it looks like a possible reason is mismatched brackets, such that the keyword is passed to `Rule` instead of `LinkExtractor`. It seems to me that in this case, however, `callback` is within the `LinkExtractor` bracket as intended.

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `callback` is definitely being passed to `LinkExtractor`. That seems to be the problem, actually, because I don't see `callback` under the expected parameters for that class in [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html).

I see that the [`Rule`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) class *does* have a callback parameter listed in the documentation. So maybe you're *supposed* to pass it to Rule instead of LinkExtractor?

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*huis.*'), callback='parse_item')
```

If you're thinking "but why did the answerer of the linked question put `callback` inside the `LinkExtractor` call?", I think you may be misinterpreting the nesting of the parentheses, which is admittedly somewhat confusing. Changing the layout makes it a little clearer:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=[r'/*'], 
            deny=('blogs/*', 'videos/*', )
        ),
        callback='parse_html'
    ), 
)
```